# Error consuming WebService with Axis2 Codegen

Tags: java, web-services, soap, lotus-notes, axis

I'm trying to consume a Webservice in Java. Therefore, I've downloaded the WSDL-file from this [site](https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3/SoftLayer_Account?wsdl). 
The first error message i got after trying it in IBM Domino Designer is:

> wsdl2 emitter timed out (content too large to handle)

The wsdl is quite big, so maybe the file is just too large for IBM Domino to handle.

The second error message after trying it in Eclipse J2EE with [Axis2Codegen Wizard](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html) is:

> An error occurred while completing process -java.lang.InterruptedException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 22: 
>   file:/C:/Users/XYZ/Softlayer/

And now I'm here, having no idea what character causes the problem. Since I'm quite new to SOAP / Webservices, there may be a chance that I'm doing something totally wrong. Otherwise there must be a problem with the .wsdl-file itself.

Question: Do you have an alternative idea who to consume the .wsdl? Are you able to consume this file, or do you get the same error message?

Comment: In Notes, have you tried copying the WSDL local and importing from there? Does the same thing happen? Creating a provider with the WSDL will sometimes give more descriptive errors as well, if WSDL content related. Also, are you creating a LS or Java consumer?

Comment: Hey @Simon, thank you for your interest. Yes, I've allready tried it with a local copy of the WSDL-File. Domino Designer is unable to import the file "WSDL2 emitter timed out (content too large to handle)".

Comment: Checked the error in question. It normally relates to network loading (ie. Server timeout). There is a timeout setting but it appears to be internal. You may need to open a PMR to get assistance.

Comment: When importing can you run 3 NSDs. Then open each NSD and look for a common thread (will mention WSDL). Post that thread in your question.